# Get data from input in each row of table

Tags: javascript

I am making a table in JavaScript using template literals, so I don't have access to each row of my table. I have a form in which my table is set and I have a number input at the end of each row. Right now, my program is only sending the quantity of the fist object to the console, but I need all of the quantities according to the id so that i can make a total at the end of my shopping cart.

I don't know if I could make a loop that goes through each row and tell me the id, price and quantity but that would be my first instinct. I am still new to JavaScript so I don't really know where to go from here.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
//load JSON file
var articles = ""
var txt = ""
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    articles = xmlhttp.responseText;

    processArticles(articles);

    var form = document.getElementById('formtable');
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');

    form.onsubmit = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log("HI");
     console.log(quantity.value);
   };
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","../articles.json",true);
xmlhttp.send();

function processArticles(articles) {
  txt = JSON.parse(articles);

  var tableStart = `
    <h2>Liste des articles</h2>
    <form id="formtable">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Article</th>
        <th>Prix</th>
        <th>Prix-Retour</th>
        <th>Quantitée maximale</th>
        <th>Projet</th>
        <th>Quantitée</th>
      </tr>`;

  var tableEnd = `
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>`;

  function articlesTemplate(txt) {
    return `
        <tr>
          <td>${txt.ID}</td>
          <td>${txt.Article }</td>
          <td>${txt.Prix}</td>
          <td>${txt.PrixRetour}</td>
          <td>${txt.QuantiteeMaximale}</td>
          <td>${txt.Projet}</td>
          <td><input type="number" id="quantity" min="1" max="5"></td>
        </tr>
    `;
  }

  let mctxt=txt.filter(value=>
    value.Projet=="mc");
    document.getElementById("tablemc").innerHTML = `
      ${tableStart}
      ${mctxt.map(articlesTemplate).join("")}
      ${tableEnd}
      `;
    ;
}
```

In my HTML, I just have a div with the id of `tablemc`.

I want to be able to see the quantity of each item with their id, so that I can make a total amount at the end of my table. Right now, it only sends the quantity of the first item and it doesn't tell me which id it is or what the price of the item is.

Comment: IDs must be unique to the entire document, so you can't use the same id attribute in every `input` element. Add an `index` parameter to `articlesTemplate`, which will be unique, then add it to your template, or concatenate "quantity" with `txt.ID`, if that value is unique. Also, `input` elements need to have a `name` attribute to be submitted, so I'd use the same code for `name` as you use for `id`.

Comment: I am guessing i can add the index like this: ```function processArticles(articles, index)``` but then how could i add it to my template and call it in my form?

Comment: Well, I said to add the `index` to `articlesTemplate` not `processArticles`. The `map` function passes the current element, the index, and the array, so when you call `mctext.map(articlesTemplate)`, you'll get the index appropriately. As far as adding it to your template; you'd add it the same way as you've added everything else; something like `id="quantity${txt.ID}" name="quantity${txt.ID}"`.

Comment: Now i guess i also have to set ```var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity${txt.ID}');```, but when i do that it tells me ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null```

Comment: Now i changed my quantity variable to this: ```var quantity = document.getElementById(`quantity${txt.ID}`);```. It doesn't give me any errors but it tells me that it is empty

Comment: `${txt.ID}` is a *replaced part of the template*. You have to replace it with the actual ID. Just look at the generated HTML in your browser's inspector and, if the ID is something like "20319", you'd see the ID of the input is "quantity20319".

Comment: So i would have to call the actual id? I can't the just call the template literal element? I am guessing i would have to make a loop to change the id of the ```document.getElement.Id()``` each time.

Comment: I works well when i call the id as quantity1 or quantity2, but i don't want to type it in each time.